# how to select subsection of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a csv as such, read it into a dataframe ,

```
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", usecols=["SupplierName', 'ContactName'])
```

is it possible to select say a particular row and then just a column from above df , as such

```
df_sub = df.iloc[1:2]
df_name = df_sub['ContactName'] or something similar
```

also, can i assign some other value , once i narrow it down one row/column , something like
df_name['ContactName'] = 'some other name', to change the value store in that cell

```
SupplierID     SupplierName             ContactName      Address          City          
   1        Exotic Liquid Charlotte        Cooper            49 Gilbert St.  Londona            
   2        New Orleans Cajun Delights  Shelley Burke    P.O. Box 78934  New Orleans            
   3        Grandma Kelly's Homestead   Regina Murphy    707 Oxford Rd.  Ann Arbor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with select row and column with `iloc` at the same time

```
df_sub = df.iloc[1:2, df.columns.get_indexer(['ContactName'])]
```